# How to display all first names starting "Ja" Using SQL

Tags: sql, database, select, pgadmin

My question is, How do I display all the customers first names that start with "Ja".

This is what I did:

```
select * from customers
where name like '%Ja%'
```

Problem here is that it displays all first and last names starting with "Ja" but I only want the first name that start with "Ja." How do I do that?

Comment: remove the first '%'?

Comment: Actually, it will show you any name *containing* `Ja`, not starting with. It should be `Ja%`. However, to answer your question about first names; you'll need to define *what* a first name is. First names aren't necessarily the *first name (by location) in the full name*. In any case, if there is a distinction between a first name and a last name, they should probably be stored in different columns (and not combined into a `name` column)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the customers those name has start with `Ja` then you need to use this

```
select * from customers
where name like 'Ja%'
```

This means name will be `Ja....`. If you use `%` at both side that will indicate all the names having `Ja` anywhere in them like `ahJar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE 'Ja%'
```

Above query returns all records having names which start with letters **Ja**.